# NodeJS parse middleware to Controller/Route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm starting now with NodeJS and I'm having a problem accessing some functions in controllers with express.

Example:

**My server.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var consign = require('consign');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');

var Recaptcha = require('express-recaptcha');
var recaptcha = new Recaptcha('blablabla', 'blablabla');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'app/views');
app.use(express.static('./app/public'));

consign()
        .include('./app/routes')
        .then('./app/models')
        .then('./app/controllers')
        .into(app);

module.exports = app;

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server ON');
});
```

**My app/routes/home.js route:**

```
module.exports = function (myapp) {
    myapp.get('/site', recaptcha.middleware.render, function (req, res) {
        myapp.app.controllers.home.pagina(myapp, req, res, {title: 'Cadastre-se', url: req.originalUrl, captcha: res.recaptcha});
    });
};
```

**My app/controllers/home.js controller:**

```
module.exports.pagina = function (myapp, req, res, page) {
    res.render("index", page);
};
```

**You are returning the error:**

```
ReferenceError: recaptcha is not defined at Function.module.exports (/Users/User/NodeJS_projects/myapp/app/routes/home.js:2)
```

If I call the middleware in the **server.js** file as follows:

```
...ss.static('./app/public'));

app.use(recaptcha());

consign()...
```

Returns the following error:

```
TypeError: recaptcha is not a function
```

How to solve this problem? Or, what would be the correct way to pass a middleware to controllers or routes?

Comment: Have you installed 'express-recaptcha' e.g. run npm install --save express-recaptcha

Comment: @MattLong Already installed. If I run the direct command on server.js, it works.

Comment: How do you expect `recaptcha.middleware.render` to be defined in `app/controllers/home.js` controller? Are you importing `recaptcha` somewhere in that file? If yes, can you please share the complete code?

Comment: @Behrooz This is the complete code. I made a correction on the home.js route that calls the pagina() function in the home.js controller

Comment: I would move lines 6-7 of server.js into a module where recaptcha would get exported. Then you can import it where you need it (those two route modules)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues. One, if you look at the documentation for the `express-recaptcha` module [here](https://github.com/pdupavillon/express-recaptcha), you need to parse the request body for this module to work. To do this you need the `body-parser` module, which you correctly have, but you also need to add the middleware:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

You can add this right after defining `app` in your `server.js` file. Then, you do not have `recaptcha` defined in your `home.js` file. You can move the following definition from `server.js` to `home.js`:

```
var Recaptcha = require('express-recaptcha');
var recaptcha = new Recaptcha('blablabla', 'blablabla');
```

Also, you added `app.use(recaptcha());` to your `server.js` file. `recaptcha` is not a function itself. It contains two middleware functions, one for rendering the widget (`recaptcha.middleware.render`) and the other for verifying the response from the widget (`recaptcha.middleware.verify`). These should be added to specific routes that are in charge of rendering and verification. I think if you look at the link I provided, it will be helpful.